# How to tell whether I'm static or an object?

Tags: php

Does anybody know offhand the way to tell whether I'm being called statically (Classname::function) or inside an object ($classInstance->function) inside a PHP method?

Comment: That's what the static keyword is there for. If you're mixing the two up you should be getting a warning.

Comment: A static function should not be called non-statically, and a non-static method should not be called statically. Yet another thing in PHP that should generate a fatal error, but does not.

Comment: In the case at hand, I had to fix a bug quickly to get to bed :)  But you're right, of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check in PHP that I'm in a static context (or not)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858538/how-do-i-check-in-php-that-im-in-a-static-context-or-not)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Admittedly not offhand...but Sean Coates has a [cool and fairly simple approach to finding this out](http://seancoates.com/blogs/schizophrenic-methods):

```
$isStatic = !(isset($this) && get_class($this) == __CLASS__);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$this` is set and equal to the class. It will be equal for an instance call and non-equal (or null) for a static call.

Comment: This is not actually correct. See my linked blog post in the accepted answer. `$this` can be set if a method is called statically, and it might not even belong to the containing class.