# How do I check in PHP that I'm in a static context (or not)?

Tags: php, methods, static

Is there any way I can check if a method is being called statically or on an instantiated object?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class Foo {
   function bar() {
      $static = !(isset($this) && $this instanceof self);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's fairly paranoid.. but nice one nonetheless

Comment: mmm ... this doesn't work, if i have a class 'baz' extending 'foo' and calling function 'bar' from baz' context, because \_\_CLASS\_\_ is still 'foo' and get_class($this) is 'baz'.

Comment: doesn't late-static-binding provide a solution for the get_class() bit?

Comment: As @harald pointed out, this is not reliable.  For example, I just found some production code that went something like this:  $foo->anotherMethod() calls B::method() which called Foo::bar().  The original $foo variable was an instance of Foo.  In this case, $this referred to the $foo instance.  I have yet to find a solution to this problem other than to tread lightly and be careful with your code design.

Comment: I had a similar issue as @harald and @Levinaris, but was able to work around it by simply testing `isset($this)`.

Comment: Maybe do `$this instanceof __CLASS__` instead of `get_class($this) == __CLASS__`?

Comment: @neubert `$this instanceof self` is working for me. `$this instanceof __CLASS__` throws a [fatal error](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46593) (at least in PHP 5.3).

Answer (score 11):

"Digging it out of debug_backtrace()" isn't too much work. debug_backtrace() had a 'type' member that is '::' if a call is static, and '->' if it is not. So:

```
class MyClass {
    public function doStuff() {
        if (self::_isStatic()) {
            // Do it in static context
        } else {
            // Do it in object context
        }
    }

    // This method needs to be declared static because it may be called
    // in static context.
    private static function _isStatic() {
        $backtrace = debug_backtrace();

        // The 0th call is to _isStatic(), so we need to check the next
        // call down the stack.
        return $backtrace[1]['type'] == '::';
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this method to my base class that all my classes extend from (although I made it public not private) and it works great :D

Comment: Are you *sure*? `type` holds the *type* of the function, which is either `static` or not; it doesn't change depending on the call protocol.

Comment: This also works great when used in a Trait. I implemented the method isStatic(), which then obtains an instance of the class when true.

Comment: For better performance, use: $backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2);

Answer (score 8):

Checking if `$this` is set won't work always.

If you call a static method from within an object, then `$this` will be set as the callers context. If you *really* want the information, I think you'll have to dig it out of `debug_backtrace`. But why would you need that in the first place? Chances are you could change the structure of your code in a way so that you don't.

Comment: I forgot about that small annoyance.  Interesting.

Comment: Wouldn't BenTheDesigner's attempt tackle this issue?

Comment: As long as `$this` isn't an instance of `Foo`, but I guess that's a bit contrived. Still, having to ask the question in the first place is a red flag to me.

Answer (score 6):

I actually use this line of code on all my scripts,it works well and it prevents errors.

```
class B{
      private $a=1;
      private static $static=2;

      function semi_static_function(){//remember,don't declare it static
        if(isset($this) && $this instanceof B)
               return $this->a;
        else 
             return self::$static;
      }
}
```

The use of instanceof is not paranoia:

If class A call class B statically function `$this` may exist on the A scope;
I know it's pretty messed up but php does it.

`instanceof` will fix that and will avoid conflicting with classes that may implement your "semi-static" functions.

Comment: What do you mean by comment "remember,don't declare it static"? This simply **won't** work, if you have _strict error reporting mode_ enabled (used mostly on final code, before production)! Because in this case you'll see notice/error saying: "Not-static methods should not be called statically". What you're proposing here seems to be as a little bit developer blah-blah. If you use function statically, you declare it with `static` keyword. Amen. No exception.

Comment: @trejder :  statically declared methods cant use $this, whether called statically or not

Comment: Please note that PHP 7 just deprecated calling non-static methods as static, will throw a deprecation warning. http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php In the future the feature may be removed altogether.

Answer (score 4):

Test for `$this`:

```
class Foo {

    function bar() {
        if (isset($this)) {
            echo "Y";
        } else {
            echo "N";
        }
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->bar(); // prints "Y"

Foo::bar(); // prints "N"
```

**Edit:** As pygorex1 points out, you can also *force* the method to be evaluated statically:

```
class Foo {

    static function bar() {
        if (isset($this)) {
            echo "Y";
        } else {
            echo "N";
        }
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->bar(); // prints "N", not "Y"!

Foo::bar(); // prints "N"
```

Comment: +1 Interesting note: try changing `function bar()` to `static function bar()` - in this case `$f->bar()`, `Foo::bar()` and `$f::bar()` are all called in static context.

Comment: Cool. I always thought it would raise an exception or so, if you'd try and call a static method from an instance. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: ´$this` is also set if the method is called statically from within another object instance, so your solution is flawed.

Answer (score 3):

Testing isset($this) wasn't working for me, as mentioned by troelskn "$this will be set as the callers context."

```
abstract class parent
{
    function bar()
    {
        if( isset( $this ) ) do_something();
        else static::static_bar();
    }

    function static static_bar()
    {
        do_something_in_static_context();
    }
}

class child extends parent
{
    ...
}

$foo = new child();
$foo->bar(); //results in do_something()
child::bar(); //also results in do_something()
```

In my case, I have a parent class with a object and static context function that performs the same task within a child class. isset( $this ) was always returning true, however, I noticed that while $this switches between being class child in object context and calling(?) class on static context, the wonderful `__class__` magic constant, remained as class parent!

Shortly there-after finding the function is_a, we can now test if we're in static context:

```
if(  is_a($this, __CLASS__) ) ...
```

Returns true on object context, false on static context.

Please test for your own implementations, as I'm only testing this for my specific scenario (a unique case of inheritance calling) in 5.3.

Unfortunately (for my case) I am yet unable to find a way to call the `static_bar()` since $this and static are referring to a separate class, and `__class__` is referring to the parent class. What I need is a way to call child::static_bar()...

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I'll add an alternative answer.

There are two magic methods

`__call($name, $arguments)`
is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.

`__callStatic($name, $arguments)`
is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in a static context.

```
<?php
class MethodTest
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
        echo "Calling object method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }

    /**  As of PHP 5.3.0  */
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        // Note: value of $name is case sensitive.
        echo "Calling static method '$name' "
             . implode(', ', $arguments). "\n";
    }
}

$obj = new MethodTest;
$obj->runTest('in object context');

MethodTest::runTest('in static context');  // As of PHP 5.3.0
```

Outputs

> Calling object method 'runTest' in object context
>   Calling static method 'runTest' in static context

Comment: I really like this one, looks elegant and uses no workarounds.

Comment: This is an awesome response, don't know why it wasn't picked as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**It's 2022 now, with php 7.4, 8: you can/should no longer be vague about the context a method will be called in.**

If a method is not declared static, 7.4 will warn you, 8 will fatal error.

If a method is declared static, `$this` is never available.

```php
<?php

class C {
   public function nonStaticMethod() {
      print isset($this) ? "instance ": "static\n";
   }
   public static function staticMethod() {
      print isset($this) ? "instance ": "static\n";
   }
}

// php 8: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method Foo::bar() cannot be called statically
// php 7.4: Deprecated: Non-static method Foo::bar() should not be called statically
C::nonStaticMethod();

C::staticMethod();

$f = new C();
$f->nonStaticMethod();
// `$this` is still not defined. It works without the instance context,
// even though you called it from an instance.
$f->staticMethod();
```

Other hacks are available, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `$this` is defined

Answer (score 1):

```
<?

class A {
    function test() {
            echo isset($this)?'not static':'static';                                }

}

$a = new A();
$a->test();
A::test();
?>
```

Edit: beaten to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a static variable and change it in the constructor.

```
private static $isInstance = false;

public function __construct()
{
    self::$isInstance = true;
}
```

Now you can check it

```
public function myMethod()
{
    if (self::$isInstance) {
        // do things
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as an instance has been crested, it will always think it's in instance context not static.

Answer (score -1):

Just return the class as new within the function.

```
return new self();
```