# Determine whether a static method has been called statically or as an instance method

Tags: php, static

In PHP, static methods can be called as if they were instance methods:

```
class A {
    public static function b() {
        echo "foo";
    }
}

$a = new A;

A::b();  //foo
$a->b(); //foo
```

Is there a way of determining inside of `b()` whether the method was called statically or not?

I've tried `isset($this)` but it returns false in both cases, and `debug_backtrace()` seems to show that both calls are actually static calls

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(57) "test.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(23)
    ["function"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["class"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "::"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
Foo
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["file"]=>
    string(57) "test.php"
    ["line"]=>
    int(24)
    ["function"]=>
    string(1) "b"
    ["class"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["type"]=>
    string(2) "::"
    ["args"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why would you need to know that anyways?

Comment: Both calls _are_ static calls. It's a static function. The function itself should have no concept of a non-static context. Why do you think you need to know this?

Comment: just curious - I was exploring the concept of (pseudo?) overloading in PHP => `Class::method($instance1, $instance2, $param)` vs. `$instance1->method($instance2, $param)` (w/ same method name)

Comment: if it takes two params in one call and three in another, chances are the method does different things depending on those. Methods should do only one thing, so you should have two methods for that. If it's just for getting variable number of arguments, use `func_get_args`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check in PHP that I'm in a static context (or not)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858538/how-do-i-check-in-php-that-im-in-a-static-context-or-not)

Answer (score 3):

The `isset` trick only works if you don't declare the method explicitly as `static`. (Because that's exactly what turns the -> object invocation into a static call.)

Methods can still be called via `class::method()` if you don't use the static modifier.

Comment: This should have been a comment, perhaps.

Comment: Calling a non-static method statically raises an E_STRICT notice as per [http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: @Chris: Yep. You will to decide between perceived code cleanliness or functionality.

Comment: @Gordon [you forgot to remove the static keyword](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AYO79e)