# PHP - Overloaded class function

Tags: php, function

Helo everyone.

I have a class **MyClass** and a function **escape**() that can be called as a static class or as an instantiated Object.

```
MyClass::_escape('..... some string...');
```

or

```
$myclass->escape();
```

What I would like is not to have the *underscore* on the staic version and for both just have the same function definition. I trie to do.

```
    class MyClass {

    public $_string = "";

      public function escape($string = null) {

            if($string == null) 
                  return new String(mysql_real_escape_string($this->_string));
            else
                  return new String(mysql_real_escape_string($string)); 

      }


   }
```

but this function fails by the PHP parser. Is there a way of doing what I attempted to above??

So to summarise, I would like the static call to look like;

```
   print Myclass::escape('some string');
```

and the instantiated call to look like;

```
   print $myobject->escape(); //Which escapes the private variable _string
```

Hope this was clear.

regards

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions .. comments. I learn a little more every day. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no parse errors in the code you posted.  In fact, it works just as you want it to work, as long as you never pass `$string` to the `escape()` method in an object context:

```
$foo = new MyClass();
$foo->_string = 'foo';
$foo->escape(); // This works.
MyClass::escape('bar'); // This works, too.
$foo->escape('baz'); // Don't do this.  It'll escape $string instead of $this->_string.
```

You could resolve this issue by [determining whether or not you're in a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858538/how-do-i-check-in-php-that-im-in-a-static-context-or-not) within the `escape()` method, instead of checking for the existence of `$string`.

Answer (score 3):

```
public function _escape($s){
  return self::escape($s);
}
```

Comment: So you suggest having both functions but the instatiated object calls the static function. If so, thats what I currently have, just would be nice to have the same function name. ..regards

Comment: this is your best bet considering your broken design

Comment: ok, so is having the same name NOT possible? Ive been coding in PHP 5 for 2 months now and just trying to  understand the restrictions

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to achieve won't work without at least some kind of error:

**Example** using `static`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);

class MyClass
{
  // note the *static* keyword
  public static function escape($string = null) {
    // $this is not defined, even if called as object-method 
    var_dump(isset($this));
  }
}

$foo = new MyClass();
$foo->escape(); // => bool(false)

MyClass::escape(); // => bool(false)
```

So, if you remove the `static` keyword and try again, you'll get:

```
$foo->escape(); // => bool(true)
```

but also:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method MyClass::escape() should
not be called statically ...
```

for

```
MyClass::escape(); // => bool(false)
```