# Check if provided "callback" argument is static

Tags: php, function

I have a function that takes a "callback" argument. This can be either a function or a static class method.

How can I detect if the method is static or not?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858538/how-do-i-check-in-php-that-im-in-a-static-context-or-not

Comment: Why does it matter? Surely `call_user_func` does all you need to do without worrying about what *kind* of callback it is?

Comment: because the callback string is stored somewhere and called at a different time (different page request). I want to make sure it's a static method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could do this with reflection, though this will be *slow*.

Presuming your callback is `$callback`:

```
if (is_array($callback)) { // a function will just be a string
    $classname = $callback[0];
    $methodname = $callback[1];

    $method = new ReflectionMethod($classname, $methodname);

    if ($method->isStatic()) {
        // method is static
    }
}
```

Note that this *doesn't* account for times when `$callback[0]` is an object, or if you have a lambda function as `$callback`, or probably all kinds of different circumstances. I don't really understand what you're looking for; this may be sufficient.