# PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, function, class, object, fatal-error

I've got a problem:

I'm writing a new WebApp without a Framework.

In my **index.php** I'm using: `require_once('load.php');`

And in **load.php** I'm using `require_once('class.php');` to load my **class.php**.

In my **class.php** I've got this error:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in class.php on line ... (in this example it would be 11)

An example how my *class.php* is written:

```
class foobar {

    public $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        global $foo;

        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function foobarfunc() {
        return $this->foo();
    }

    public function foo() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
```

In my *index.php* I'm loading maybe `foobarfunc()` like this:

```
foobar::foobarfunc();
```

but can also be

```
$foobar = new foobar;
$foobar->foobarfunc();
```

Why is the error coming?

Comment: Coincidentally I was struggling with this error for about 3 hours yesterday! :)

Comment: @jack in my case I was using **this** on static function

Answer (score 251, accepted):

> In my index.php I'm loading maybe
> foobarfunc() like this:

```
 foobar::foobarfunc();  // Wrong, it is not static method
```

> but can also be

```
$foobar = new foobar;  // correct
$foobar->foobarfunc();
```

You can not invoke the method this way because it is not a static method.

```
foobar::foobarfunc();
```

You should instead use:

```
$foobar->foobarfunc();
```

If however, you have created a static method something like:

```
static $foo; // your top variable set as static

public static function foobarfunc() {
    return self::$foo;
}
```

then you can use this:

```
foobar::foobarfunc();
```

Comment: The variables having the same name is not an issue. `$this->foo` is a class member, while `$foo` is just a variable in the function scope (imported from global scope). Function names with the same name as a member are also not an issue.

Comment: You cannot use `$this` in a static method.

Comment: It's funny how a completely wrong answer gets upvotes nonetheless. $this is not available in class context. The OP will get the same error from the example above.

Comment: @Ycaoby, @Gordon: I just copy-pasted his code, did not notice the `$this` keyword in there, fixed any ways thanks.

Comment: @Sarfraz No offense, but it is still wrong. You *can* call an instance method with `::`. It is against `E_STRICT`, but it *does* work as long as the method body does not reference the instance scope, e.g. uses `$this`. Also, `self::foo` will not point to `$this->foo`. It references a class **constant**. Both, `self::foo` and `self::$foo` would raise a Fatal Error.

Comment: @Gordon: he wants to return public variable set on the top.

Comment: @Sarfraz Yes, I know, which is why I am complaining about your solution. The public member `foo` cannot be called from class scope, unless you either declare it static or make it into a constant.

Comment: @Sarfraz okay, maybe I'm too picky today, but this will still raise a fatal as self:foo => constant while self::$foo => static member.

Comment: @Sarfraz it's better now. Sorry for pestering you, but as this became the accepted answer, I felt it necessary to point these things out :) Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Gordon: I highly appreciate your comment, and guess what your pestering has been really generous for me as i was missing too much. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately if `__construct` is private for whatever reason, it doesn't work, e.g.: `private function __construct()`

Answer (score 34):

You are calling a non-static method :

```
public function foobarfunc() {
    return $this->foo();
}
```

Using a static-call :

```
foobar::foobarfunc();
```

When using a static-call, the function will be called *(even if not declared as `static`)*, but, as there is no instance of an object, there is no `$this`.

So :

- You should not use static calls for non-static methods
- Your static methods (or statically-called methods) can't use $this, which normally points to the current instance of the class, as there is no class instance when you're using static-calls.

Here, the methods of your class are using the current instance of the class, as they need to access the `$foo` property of the class.

This means your methods need an instance of the class -- which means they cannot be static.

This means you shouldn't use static calls : you should instanciate the class, and use the object to call the methods, like you did in your last portion of code :

```
$foobar = new foobar();
$foobar->foobarfunc();
```

For more informations, don't hesitate to read, in the PHP manual :

- The [Classes and Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) section
- And the [Static Keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) page.

Also note that you probably don't need this line in your `__construct` method :

```
global $foo;
```

Using the [`global` keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) will make the `$foo` variable, declared outside of all functions and classes, visibile from inside that method... And you probably don't have such a `$foo` variable.

To access the `$foo` [class-property](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), you only need to use `$this->foo`, like you did.

Answer (score 13):

If you are invoking `foobarfunc` with [resolution scope operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) (`::`), then you are calling it [statically](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php), e.g. on the class level instead of the instance level, thus you are *using `$this` when not in object context*. `$this` does not exist in class context.

If you enable `E_STRICT`, PHP will raise a Notice about this:

```
Strict Standards: 
Non-static method foobar::foobarfunc() should not be called statically
```

Do this instead

```
$fb = new foobar;
echo $fb->foobarfunc();
```

On a sidenote, I suggest not to use `global` inside your classes. If you need something from outside inside your class, pass it through the constructor. This is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and it will make your code much more maintainable and less dependant on outside things.

Answer (score 7):

First you understand one thing, **$this** inside a class denotes the **current object**.
That is which is you are created out side of the class to call class function or variable.

So when you are calling your class function like foobar::foobarfunc(), object is not created.
But inside that function you written return $this->foo(). Now here $this is nothing. Thats why its saying *Using $this when not in object context in class.php*

Solutions:

1. Create a object and call foobarfunc().
2. Call foo() using class name inside the foobarfunc().

Comment: or just use self:: instead of $this

Answer (score 6):

## Fast method : *(new foobar())->foobarfunc();*

You need to load your class replace :

```
foobar::foobarfunc();
```

by :

```
(new foobar())->foobarfunc();
```

or :

```
$Foobar = new foobar();
$Foobar->foobarfunc();
```

Or make *static* function to use `foobar::`.

```
class foobar {
    //...

    static function foobarfunc() {
        return $this->foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you call the function in a static context, `$this` simply doesn't exist.

You would have to use `this::xyz()` instead.

To find out what context you're in when a function can be called both statically and in an object instance, a good approach is outlined in this question: [**How to tell whether I’m static or an object?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647735/how-to-tell-whether-im-static-or-an-object)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me to be a bug in PHP.
The error

> 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context
> in'

appears in the function using `$this`, but the error is that the calling function is using non-static function as a static. I.e:

```
Class_Name
{
    function foo()
    {
        $this->do_something(); // The error appears there.
    }
    function do_something()
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

While the error is here:

```
Class_Name::foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$foobar = new foobar;` put **the class** foobar in $foobar, **not the object**. To get the object, you need to add parenthesis: `$foobar = new foobar();`

Your error is simply that you call a method on a class, so there is no `$this` since `$this` only exists in objects.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the Class method using this `foobar->foobarfunc();`