# Using $this when not in object context in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-components, yii-events

Iam getting an error like `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in ..\controllers\ServiceRequestController.php on line 661` when calling a view file using controller action from EasyTabs extension.
 Iam calling the controller action like this in the view file
 `ServiceRequestController::actionTest();`
 and in controller

```
     public static function actionTest()  
   {
        $this->redirect('test');
    }
```

How can I get rid of this error?? When I googled, I found that `$this cannot be used in a static method.` . So I tried out using
 `$model = new ServiceRequest();
           $model->Test();` in my view file.But it shows the error as `ServiceRequest and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "actionTest".`
Can anyone help me fixing the error? Thanks in advance
I tried to fix using this link . But I think Iam mistaken. [PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

Answer (score 9):

Do not use the keyword `static` when you define the action.

You can read more about static methods and properties here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
   self::actionTest();
```

instead

```
   ServiceRequestController::actionTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the $this keyword the object needs to have been instantiated at some point.  If you've got a class:

```
class Example {

    private $word = 'hello';

    public static function hello() {
        echo 'I can be called by writing:';
        echo 'Example::yo()';
    }

    public function world() {
        echo 'If this class has been instantiated, ( new Example; )';
        echo '$this->word will be hello';
        echo 'If this class hasn't been instantiated, you will get your error';
    }
}
```

A particular instance of a class can be referred to as $this from methods that are inside of it.

You could write:

```
$example1 = new Example;
$example2 = new Example;
$example3 = new Example;
```

Inside of $example1, $this would refer to the same thing that $example1 refers to from outside of it.  So you could change $example1's $word like so:

```
$example1->word = 'yo';    // from outside of the class
$this->word = 'yo';        // from inside of the class
```

Before you're instantiated the class with the new keyword though, there is no $this in existence yet.  The class is a blueprint, and you create objects out of it using the new keyword which can then be referred to from within as $this.

Comment: how can I implement it in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error for yii2 by correcting my URL e.g.

```
 http://localhost/e-compare2/backend/web/index.php?r=crud/make
```