# PHP Object Visibility and Inheritance

Tags: php, oop

I'm reading this tutorial about PHP Classes. I haven really fully understand it, can anyone help me out here?
I came across this class

```
  <?php
      class foo{
         private $_var;
         static function bar(){
             return $this->_var;
         }
         function setVar($value = null){
             $this->_var = $value;
         }
      }
?>
```

It says there's something wrong with the class. Is it that obvious? I dont know what's wrong with it... is it the underscore before the var?
Edit: if I run this code

```
 $x = new foo();
 $x->setVar(1);
 echo $x->bar();
```

I get this message Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in main.php on line 6 PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in main.php on line 6

Comment: Try to use search first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you use static context, you have to use self instead of $this. So, in this case, you'd have to change

```
return $this->_var;
```

with

```
return self::$_var;
```

**UPDATE:**

Either do this:

```
// traditional object context
class foo {
   private $_var;

   function bar(){
       return $this->_var;
   }

   function setVar($value = null){
       $this->_var = $value;
   }
}

$x = new foo();
$x->setVar(1);
echo $x->bar();
```

or do

```
// static context
class foo {
   static $_var;

   static function bar(){
       return self::$_var;
   }

   static function setVar($value = null){
       self::$_var = $value;
   }
}

foo::setVar(1);
echo foo::bar();
```

Comment: Right, that was a typo.

Comment: After I change it, i get the following error Access to undeclared static property: foo::$_var on line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Static function is called by class name or self(in the called function is in same class), you cannot call it on $this

```
 echo $x->bar(); // this is wrong
```

it should be

```
 echo foo::bar();
```