# PHP 7.2 : how to check if in static mode

Tags: php, this

Situation:

```
Class A{
    public function F(){
        var_dump($this);
    }
}

A::F();
```

When doing this I get **PHP Fatal error:Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context**.

1. Shouldn't I get a NULL or something, instead of the error?
2. How do I check (in PHP 7.2!!!) if in object context?

Thx!

Comment: PHP allows calling non-static methods statically, but emits a warning.  The real question is why are you calling this statically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

Comment: Did you find the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is not available in static calls, you need to use `self::` but keep in mind these are not interchangeable equivalents.