# How to assign function reference for a function inside a class

Tags: php, function, reference

Reference: Am using Slim Framework to develop Rest API application.
Problem: While doing so, used static functions. However, one of the functions that were called from my api code, threw an error "Using $this when not in object context". Since I cannot change the code being called which is generating the issue, I need to change my code.

Sample Code before change:
    $app->post($mer_token_endpoint, get_token);

The rest of the code is fine, except the issue of $this. Wherever it is not called, those APIs work fine.

Now I changed the code to:

```
class Token {
    public function get_token(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
.... code ....
    }
}
$TokenObj = new Token();
$app->post($token_endpoint, $TokenObj->get_token);
```

How do I pass the reference of the function get_token declared in the class Token in the function post ?

Comment: Maybe this will help `$app->post($token_endpoint, [$TokenObj, 'get_token']);`

Comment: The solution from Nikita worked pretty good. Thankx.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right but i want to know more about your code. Do you use static property in your function because if you have static class or function we use self instead of $this to access static property also without creating object

Comment: Actually there is only 1 function inside the class. That function in turn includes another file, which we cannot change. Inside THAT file, is the problem "Using $this when not in object context" being generated.

Comment: Did you see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context

Comment: Again here this error mention about static and how to use it