# FATAL ERROR: Using $this when not in object context, but it works anyway

Tags: php, oop, object, this

So, there are a lot of similar questions about this, but in the application I can’t get it right...
And I’m confused, because it’s working on other functions...

So... the code has a constructor like this...

```
public function getMontoDescuentosRealizados($idPropiedad, $idArriendo, $idEstado = 4, $idTipoReceptor = 1)
{
    $db = $this->db;
    $strWhere = ($idArriendo > 0) ? " AND ard.IDArriendoGarantia='" . $idArriendo . "'" : "";
    $query = "SELECT SUM(ardd.MontoCuota) as Descuento
            FROM descuentos_consolidados as ard
            INNER JOIN cuotas_consolidados AS ardd ON (ard.IDConsolidado=ardd.IDConsolidado AND ardd.nCuota=0)
            WHERE ard.Autorizado IN (1)
                AND ard.IDPropiedad=" . $idPropiedad . $strWhere;
    #error_log($query);
    $sql = $db->query($query);
    $row = $sql->fetch_array();
    return ($row["Descuento"] > 0) ? $row["Descuento"] : 0;
}
```

And there is just one function, that doesn’t work properly... and I don’t know what more I can do... I tried some solutions, but they don’t seem to fix the problem...

This is the Stack Overflow question that I’d been checking
a lot: *[PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)*

Comment: You've probably got PHP5 and you're calling the function statically like `MyClass::TheFunction()`. You can't do that. You have to instantiate an object with `$obj = new MyClass()` and then call the function with `$obj->TheFunction()`.

Comment: *"And there is just one function, that doesnt work properly."* - by *"just one function"* do you mean it's a "regular" global function, not part of a class?

Comment: @AlexHowansky The php version could affect this??? cause this program is a local copy, and works on the other pcs... and, the code its just that, its not called with "::"

Comment: @CD001 There are a lot of them starting like that, and they work fine... its just 1 of 32 functions... the other 31 works perfectly.

Comment: Calling a non-static function statically became an error in 7, but you're not getting that error, so I presume you're on 5. Post the function that contains the line where the error is.

Comment: where is the class for this? you're obviously using OOP.

Comment: @AlexHowansky currently im using 7.2.18, my coworker is using that too... i paste the complete function so you can check it

Comment: Presuambly its the `$db = $this->db;` portion causing the error.
Is this function part of a class? or is it just a single file with this function?

From the descriptions so far, it doesn't sound like the function is part of a class.

Comment: @AlexHowansky You where right, it was the php version... we where using the php7 when the program was code on php5... we tune down the version and the code works fine. (the program was using 5.3, and we were using 7.3 .. we put the 5.6 and its working)

Comment: Please don't use PHP 5. This is irresponsible. Fix your code. Also don't put solved in the question. Use answer space for the solution.

Comment: Its not my decision, its not my app :C i just work here... and where is the answer space ??

Comment: So, i found that the problem was the php version. with you guys, but now im blocked cause the question has a dislike, can u help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was checking the PHP version of the program. 
The program was created using PHP 5.3, and we were using 7.3. 
Using [WAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)#Variants), we configured the PHP to 5.6 and it works fine.

Thanks to [Alex Howansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453002/alex-howansky) for putting an eye on the PHP version.