# please help Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /antivirus_scan.php:1 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Tags: javascript, php, html

please help I've got a problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in
> D:\xampp\htdocs\admin\antivirus\antivirus_scan.php:1
> Stack trace:
> #0
> {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin\antivirus\antivirus_scan.php on
> line 1

```
<?php $this->load->view('admin/theme/message'); ?>
<section class="content-header">
    <h1 class = 'text-info'><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> <?php echo $this->lang->line("malware scan");?></h1>
</section>
<section class="content">  
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="grid_container" style="width:100%; height:720px;">
                <table 
                id="tt"  
                class="easyui-datagrid" 
                url="<?php echo base_url()."antivirus/scan_data"; ?>" 

                pagination="true" 
                rownumbers="true" 
                toolbar="#tb" 
                pageSize="10" 
                pageList="[5,10,15,20,50,100]"  
                fit= "true" 
                fitColumns= "true" 
                nowrap= "true" 
                view= "detailview"
                idField="id"
                >
```

**message.php**

```
    <?php 
    if($this->session->flashdata('success_message')==1)
    {       
        echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-center'><h4 style='margin:0;'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> ".$this->lang->line("your data has been successfully stored into the database.")."</h4></div>";
    }

    if($this->session->flashdata('warning_message')==1)
    echo "<div class='alert alert-warning text-center'><h4 style='margin:0;'><i class='fa fa-warning'></i> ".$this->lang->line("'something went wrong, please try again.")."</h4></div>";

    if($this->session->flashdata('error_message')==1)
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'><h4 style='margin:0;'><i class='fa fa-remove'></i> ".$this->lang->line("your data has been failed to stored into the database.")."</h4></div>";

        
    if($this->session->flashdata('delete_success_message')==1)
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-center'><h4 style='margin:0;'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> ".$this->lang->line("your data has been successfully deleted from the database.")."</h4></div>";
    
    if($this->session->flashdata('delete_error_message')==1)
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-center'><h4 style='margin:0;'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> ".$this->lang->line("your data has been failed to delete from the database.")."</h4></div>";
    

    if($this->session->flashdata('not_exist_message')==1)
    echo "<div class='alert alert-warning text-center'><h4 style='margin:0;'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> ".$this->lang->line("sorry! your data does not exist.")."</h4></div>";

    if($this->session->flashdata('available_error')==1)
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'><h4 style='margin:0;'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'></i> ".$this->lang->line("this book isn't available right now.")."</h4></div>";


?>
```

Comment: **Is this is your problem ? ️ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context**

Comment: @ Muhammed Rahif please explain how to fix

Comment: You can only use `$this` inside a class method. Apparently, you're not doing so. If you want to use `$this` like that, make sure message.php is included inside a method.

Comment: not working this method