# Stripe PHP Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, stripe-payments

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object
> context in
> E:...\Invoice.php:237 Stack
> trace:
> #0 E:...\subscription.php(67): Stripe\Invoice::sendInvoice('in_1M4MW6ABdULn...', Array)
> #1 {main}   thrown in E:...\Invoice.php on
> line 237

getting this error when sending invoice after subscription in stripe.

```
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::sendInvoice(
  $stripe_subscription->latest_invoice,
  []
);


$stripe_subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(
     [ 'customer' => $stripe_customer->id, 
       'payment_behavior' => 'allow_incomplete',
       'items' => [ [ 'price' => $price->id, ], ],
        'metadata' => ['Address' => "address"], 
     ]
     );
```

Comment: THIS: [PHP Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350937/php-fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

Comment: No that's different question I have issues with stripe

Comment: The cause is the same. It doesn't matter what you're using, in PHP the reason for this error is these causes: using `$this` when you're using a non-object or a static-object. If your problem is Stripe then double and triple check the Stripe documentation and be sure to use the correct documentation for your correct version of Stripe. You may need to download and install the later version of Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such method as sendInvoice like that in the Stripe library.

You get this error because sendInvoice is an instance method that requires you to have an Invoice object, you can't call it statically like that.

The correct way to do this in the latest version of the library is

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_test_xxxx'
);

$stripe_subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->create([.......]);

$invoice = $stripe->invoices->sendInvoice(
  $stripe_subscription->latest_invoice,
  []
);
```

If you're using an old version of the library, I think you have to retrieve the object first to be able to call `sendInvoice` on it. But you should not use this old legacy approach.

```
$invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($stripe_subscription->latest_invoice);
$invoice->sendInvoice([]);
```