# How can I tell if a function is being called statically in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell whether I’m static or an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647735/how-to-tell-whether-im-static-or-an-object)

Let's say I have a `FooClass` with a `bar()` method. Inside of the `bar()` method, is there any way to tell if it's being called statically or not, so I can treat these two cases differently?

```
FooClass::bar();
$baz = new FooClass();
$baz->bar();
```

Comment: You probably should think about a redesign of the class if you want to have a method that should be both statically and non-statically... why do you want to do this?

Comment: turn on E_STRICT error reporting to make php scream at you when you do it wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class FooClass {

    function bar() {
        if ( isset( $this ) && get_class($this) == __CLASS__ ) {
            echo "not static";
        }
        else {
            echo "static";
        }
    }

}

FooClass::bar();
$baz = new FooClass();
$baz->bar();
```

Comment: Thats it, but wrap `$this` in `isset()` to not trigger any additional notice

Comment: This only works in the global scope.  If you call it from another class, $this will be set, just not the object you want.  Might want to try `isset($this) && get_class($this) == __CLASS__`

Comment: If FooClass is inherited by a new class, will this work? __CLASS__ provides the class name of the file it is declared in, so that would be FooClass and presumably not InheritedFooClass that extends FooClass?