# How can you know the calling method type in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tell whether I’m static or an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647735/how-to-tell-whether-im-static-or-an-object)
>   [How can I tell if a function is being called statically in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824143/how-can-i-tell-if-a-function-is-being-called-statically-in-php)

I meant if you call the method in this way `class::method()` or in this way 
`$class->method()` How do I know which way was called method in the same method?

Comment: Heh, good finds guys. I'm flagging the two newer incarnations as a duplicate of the oldest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shouldn't mix `static` with `non-static` methods while calling them, but you can check inside your method if exists `$this`.

```
$staticcalled = isset($this);
```

Comment: +1, but there shouldn't even have to be a way to check it. Like you said, don't mix static and non-static. It's a shame PHP even allows it.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Not really. `function foo($bar) { $bar->Baz(); }` If I know there's a static `Baz` in any `$bar` I'm given, this works. Otherwise I have to know the concrete type, breaking duck typing.

Comment: "Mixing" static and non-static methods is not necessarily an indication of bad design; it might be just working around PHP's moronic insistence that you cannot call the same method both as static and as non-static (with `E_STRICT` in effect), _but_ also that you cannot have _two separate methods_ with the same name, one being static and the other non-static.