# Laravel - Create method that can be called both statically and non-statically

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wanted to create a method in the User model that behaves differently when called statically or non-statically.
Basically it should do this:

```
public function foo() {
    // based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824143/how-can-i-tell-if-a-function-is-being-called-statically-in-php
    if(isset($this) && get_class($this) == __CLASS__) {
        $static = true;
    } else {
        $static = false;
    }
    if($static)
        $user = Auth::user();
    else
        $user = $this;
    // Do stuff with the user
    return $user->bar;
    // ...
}
```

But it gives me the error:
`Non-static method User::foo() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`.

Comment: With a Facade and a Service Provider you can do that. At your vendor dir you may find some examples. Also check this link, http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-develop-packages-using-the-workbench

Comment: @user2094178 That seems to be a huge lot of work just to do what I want (basically define the object to be used, based on the way the function was called). I was actually expecting that a simple check would be enough, like in my example.

Comment: Yes, although facades and service providers are the laravelish way, but not for models, I overlooked it initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically:

You can call static methods from a non-static method but not vice versa.

So you can also use magic methods like this:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    return call_user_func(get_class_name($this) .'::'. $method, $args);
}
```

Like this, you can call every static method with the syntax of a non-static method.

Comment: This feels dirty and really non-standard / non-laravelish. Plus, will it be possible for the function to identify the way it as called like my example?

Comment: I'm just showing what you could do. Use it to create the function behavior you need.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* possible to define the same method twice; statically and non-statically.

However, you could achieve this by using the magic methods `__call` and `__callStatic`

```
class User {
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if (method_exists($this, 'instance_' . $method)) {
            return call_user_func_array([$this, 'instance_' . $method], $args);
        }
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {
        if (method_exists(__CLASS__, 'static_' . $method)) {
            return call_user_func_array([__CLASS__, 'static_' . $method], $args);
        }
    }
}
```

This would pass calls to `$user->fn()` and `User::fn()` to `$user->instance_fn()` and `User::static_fn()`.